# Trying to parse large CSV, can't split and can't find second newline

Tags: apex, csv, string

I have a csv with about 24,000 lines that I need to parse in apex. I tried splitting the string by newline ('\n'), but got a limit error:

```
System.LimitException: Regex too complicated
```

I tried looping through and getting the left of the string for each newline:

```
pos = contents.Indexof('\n');
String this_line = contents.left(pos);
```

I know this will get me into limits issues, but I want to see if I can even start with the parsing.

For this method, the above snippet only finds the first newline.

In order to make sure I wasn't having dos/unix errors with newlines, I changed the csv to have the following string as line delimiter: ~~~. This did not make a difference.

Sample Content:

```
id,email_address,optin_status,optin_status_last_updated~~~3,082790@test.com,manually_uploaded,""~~~5,0@test.com,bounced,2011-10-31 18:10:40~~~7,101k@test.com,manually_uploaded,""~~~9,1254@test.com,bounced,2012-05-24 14:05:02~~~11,134@test.com,manually_uploaded,""~~~13,1613@test.com,manually_uploaded,""~~~15,123na@test.com,unsubscribed,2012-12-03 15:02:56~~~17,123tst@test.com,manually_uploaded,""~~~19,123test@test.com,manually_uploaded,""~~~21,12@test.com,unsubscribed,2012-11-28 22:56:58~~~23,12ser@test.com,manually_uploaded,""~~~25,152t@test.com,manually_uploaded,""~~~27,16e@test.com,manually_uploaded,""~~~29,17@test.com,manually_uploaded,""~~~31,180@test.com,manually_uploaded,""~~~33,1vz@test.com,manually_uploaded,""~~~35,1a@test.com,manually_uploaded,""~~~37,1ov@test.com,manually_uploaded,""~~~39,1d@1d.com,bounced,2012-02-10 00:32:17~~~41,1gabrman@test.com,unsubscribed,2012-01-11 20:36:35~~~43,1libbypollak@gmail.com,bounced,2012-01-23 18:02:27~~~45,1on1@aish.com,manually_uploaded,""~~~47,1stmusketeer@gmail.com,manually_uploaded,""~~~49,1tman@test.com,manually_uploaded,""~~~51,21vin@test.com,unsubscribed,2012-02-05 04:11:28~~~53,22im@test.com,manually_uploaded,""~~~
```

All emails have been changed to ensure privacy.

Code:

```
Integer count = 0;
    Integer pos = 100;
    while(count < 1000 && pos > 0){
        pos = contents.Indexof('~~~');
        String this_line = contents.left(pos);
        lines.add(this_line);
        contents = contents.remove(this_line);
        System.debug('the current pos: ' + pos + ' and the new position will be: ' 
            + contents.IndexOf('~~~'));
        count = count + 1;
    }
```

Debug Log:

```
21:22:25.134 (1134910000)|USER_DEBUG|[57]|DEBUG|the current pos: 55 and the new position will be: 0
21:22:25.135 (1135010000)|USER_DEBUG|[57]|DEBUG|the current pos: 0 and the new position will be: 0
21:22:25.135 (1135081000)|USER_DEBUG|[61]|DEBUG|the number of lines: 2
```

Does anyone have any ideas here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Best String Methods**

I've been wondering about your use of [String.remove](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_String_remove.htm) in your above code. This method is described as follows. Thus if you have identical lines in your CSV this will for sure not be what your expecting, which i assume was just to remove the last line read.

> Removes all occurrences of the specified substring and returns the String result.

You should consider using [String.substring](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_String_substring_2.htm) to chop your way along the string (though reviewing the ever growing array of String methods, suggests maybe [String.substringAfter](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_String_substringAfter.htm) might also be worth a try).

**Example Line Reader**

I recently used the following Iterator implementation (useful for Batch Apex integration) to parse some Apex code this should work for your use case. I've modified the LINE_SEPARATOR variable to based on a CSV file I've used in the past (from Excel), though there is no standard specification on this you will have to stipulate and/or make it a configuration option.

```
LineReader lineReader = new LineReader(csvFile);
List<String> newLines = new List<String>();
while(lineReader.hasNext())
{
    // Read line
    String line = lineReader.next();
}

/**
 * Utility class to iterate over lines
 **/
public class LineReader 
    implements Iterator<string>, Iterable<string>
{       
    private String LINE_SEPARATOR = '\r\n';

    private String textData;

    public LineReader(String textData)
    {       
        this.textData = textData;
    }

    public Boolean hasNext()
    {
        return textData.length() > 0 ? true : false;
    }   

    public String next()
    {
        String row = null;
        Integer endPos = textData.indexOf(LINE_SEPARATOR);
        if(endPos == -1)
        {
            row = textData;
            textData = '';
        }
        else
        {
            row = textData.subString(0, endPos);
            textData = textData.subString(endPos + LINE_SEPARATOR.length(), textData.length());             
        }
        return row;
    }

    public Iterator<String> Iterator()
    {
        return this;   
    }           
}
```

**Batch Apex Consideration**

Quite a large CSV file to parse, in the statement governor free world, this type of processing stands a better chance. Though depending on what your doing with the parsed data you may still run into issues. There is an approach described in more detail [here](http://developer.financialforce.com/customizations/importing-large-csv-files-via-batch-apex/) which uses Batch Apex you might want to look at (not the global keyword is not needed these days).

Comment: @Andrew This is a very nice approach. Helped me to solve a problem for my project.