# Salesforce Apex Regex too complicated error

Tags: apex, webservices, error-messages, regular-expressions

I am working on an apex class which is making a webservice callout to an external system and with the response that I get, I am updating couple of fields on the Account object. Unfortunately, this webservice is not batched or bulkified, so I need to call this service once per account and process it one at a time. The webservice response is sometimes too big (around 1MB when saved to a file). Most of the responses are processed fine and very few of them failing with the error message "Regex too complicated".

The statement that is causing the response processing to fail is below.

```
strResponse = strResponse.replaceAll('"system"','"smsystem"');
```

As you can see, I am not using a pattern matcher or any kind of Regular expression. I am not sure why I am getting this error message with just a replaceAll() method.

Can someone help me in avoiding this error message?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000325937&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Replace all takes first parameter as Regex `replaceAll(regExp, replacement)` so implicitly you are using the regex match. As mention by @identigral above, it depends on content of your `strResponse` variable. If it is too complex, you can break the string and replace https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23515/trying-to-parse-large-csv-cant-split-and-cant-find-second-newline

Comment: see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252997/regex-too-complicated-replaceall-large-strings-preprocessed-before-deseriali

Answer (score 1):

`System.Exception: Regex too complicated` is a runtime error that happens for one of two reasons. Either 1) the Matcher is too complex or 2) the Pattern is too complex. I know you're not explicitly creating a Pattern and using a Matcher, but because `String.replaceAll` accepts a regular expression as its first argument, there are regular expressions being used within the method.

In your example the Pattern is straightforward, which rules out #2. You mention in your question that the callout response can be in excess of 1 MB. That leads me to believe there are too many matches for the method to handle.

> Salesforce limits the number of times an input sequence for a regular expression can be accessed to 1,000,000 times. If you reach that limit, you receive a runtime error.

> Therefore the Matcher string can’t be longer than 1M characters. In this case, you should check the length of the Matcher string to prevent it from running if the string is over 1M characters.

Depending on the nature of the text you're manipulating there may be a way to avoid checking so much of it or batching the operations that need to occur in Apex to avoid this error. But I think we would need to know more details about what you're trying to accomplish and how often this code needs to run.

Comment: The total number of characters in the webservice response is only 880,000. So, I am not sure how it hits the limit. The entire response is a single line message.

Comment: The number of lines is pretty meaningless in this case (line endings are just more characters after all). I'm not sure if there's a way to get a handle on how much processing `String.replaceAll` is doing, especially without knowing the underlying implementation in Salesforce. But there may be more efficient patterns. The documentation says the regular expression implementation adheres to the [Java 6 implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). You may also be able to safely ignore most of the text that you're searching. We'd need an example.

Comment: Thank you for this.  The challenge is when you have dynamic information you need to be able to prevent this error in the first place since it is an uncatchable "governor limit" error.  I am getting this on the `Matcher.find()` method and only for a small subset of strings processed.